# Sparse Spatial Weight Matrix using longitude and latitude in R

Tags: r, spatial

Quick overview: I need a function that takes longitude and latitude data and outputs a matrix with Wij the inverse distances\zeros if distance(i,j) is below\above a max distance. And it needs to work for a large data set.

Explanation:
I have a data set of 40,000 observations relating deforestation. I am looking at how deforestation is related spatially and therefore would like to create a spatial weights matrix. The data are longitude and latitude for the centroids of different areas.

I would love to have W = SpatWeight(long,lat,max) 
where long and lat are vectors of coordinates, max is a distance scalar and W is a sparse matrix where Wij is  the inverse distance(Km) between point i and point j (with Wij = 0 if i==j or dist(i,j) > max).

As an example, I would like SpatWeight(c(0,45,45,180),c(0,45,0,0),15000) to output

```
[1,] .            1.497133e-04 0.0001996178 .           
[2,] 0.0001497133 .            0.0001996178 7.485666e-05
[3,] 0.0001996178 1.996178e-04 .            .           
[4,] .            7.485666e-05 .            .
```

The code I have written so far is:

```
  library(fields) #for rdist.earth
  SpatWeight <- function(long,lat,max) {
  W = rdist.earth(cbind(long,lat),miles=F) #Gives km distance matrix
  W[W > max] <- 0 #makes observations beyond max dist zero
  W <- ifelse(W!=0,1/W,W) #inverts non-zero distances
  for(i in 1:dim(W)[1]) {W[i,i] = 0} #because same observation is not always exactly zero, makes diagonal zero
  W <- Matrix(W,sparse=T) #Makes matrix sparse
  return(W)}
```

My issue, besides not having written good code :-), is that the matrix with the actual data is too large for the computer memory.

Any help with how to go about this would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks again!
-Sean

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a code myself which runs on a large data set. Am posting it here in case any wayward traveler runs into the same problems I was having. Hope it helps someone :-)

```
SpatialWeight <- function(SortedData,max,DistFunc = function(x){return(1/x)},rownormal=F){ 
  #Creates A spatial weights matrix for large data set.
  #
  #Args:
  # Inputs data: Data must be a data frame with columns Pos, latitude and longitude
  #   -Pos is a position vector from 1:nrow(Data)
  #   -latitude must be sorted from smallest to largest.
  # max: maximum distance in km for spatial correlation
  # DistFunc: function to calculate spatial weights. Defaults to inverse distance 1/dist(i,j)
  # rownormal: Whether the matrix should be normalized by row. Either TRUE or FALSE. Defaults to FALSE.
  #Returns:
  # Sparse Matrix of size=nrow(SortedData) of spatial weights.
  DegLat <- 40008 / 360 #Based on circumfrence by poles
  DegLong <- 40075/ 360 #Based on circumfrence by equator. If using data close to the pole may change number 
                        #to increase efficiency
  len = dim(SortedData)[1] #Lenght of Data
  lat = SortedData$latitude #latitude Data
  long = SortedData$longitude #Longitude Data
  M = Matrix(0,nrow=len,ncol=len,sparse=T) #Sparse Matrix 
  latmin = 1; latmax = 1 #Used for bounding rectangle
  for(r in 1:len) {#Main Loop
    LatMin = lat[r] - max/DegLat #Minimum latitude
    LatMax = lat[r] + max/DegLat #Max Lat
    LongMin = long[r] - max/DegLong #Min Long
    LongMax = long[r] + max/DegLong   #Max Long
    #The following code makes a subset of data which has a latitude within max length
    #This reduces the set we need to calculate distance with and therefore increases the speed
    #!!!!!!!!!!DATA MUST BE SORTED BY LATITUDE!!!!!!!!
    while(LatMin < lat[latmin]) { 
      if(latmin-1 == 0) {break}
      else {latmin = latmin-1}}
    while(LatMax >lat[latmax]) {
      if(latmax + 1 > len){break}
      else {latmax = latmax+1}}
    SubGroup = SortedData[latmin:latmax,]
    #Next we subset by longitude to get a bounding rectangle.
    SubGroup = SubGroup[which(SubGroup$longitude > LongMin & SubGroup$longitude < LongMax),] #Subsets by longitude
    W = distGeo(c(long[r],lat[r]),SubGroup[,c('longitude','latitude')])/1000 #Finally gets distance for subset
    W[W > max] <- 0 #Makes far distances zero
    W = ifelse(W!=0,DistFunc(W),W) #Applies distance function (default inverse distance)
    if(rownormal==T) {W=W/sum(W)}  #normalizes by row
    M[r,SubGroup$Pos] = W }        #Adds data to sparse Matrix
  return(M)}
```